# I want that the studentid table field with zreo value is not insert,i do this by using trigger but it still allow to insert them

Tags: mysql, sql

Still allow insert zero value..

```
    CREATE TRIGGER check_my_constraint BEFORE insert ON `personal_details`
         FOR EACH ROW 
         BEGIN
         DECLARE msg varchar(255);
         IF (NEW.studentid<0)
         THEN
            SET msg = concat('Constraint my_constraint violated: studentid must not be zero ', cast(new.studentid as char));
            SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = msg;
         END IF; 
         END ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only check for *less than* zero. You will have to check for *less than or equal to* zero:

```
IF (NEW.studentid <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition -

`IF (NEW.studentid<0)` => `IF (NEW.studentid <= 0)`

Comment: @There is a dream I am living T Welcome))